# recreate multi-token strings from tokens given indices and text source

Tags: python, string, iteration, string-matching, python-re

I'm preparing a script that reconstitutes multi-token strings from a tokenized text for tokens that have specific labels. My tokens are associated with their start and end indices in the original text.

This is an example piece of text:

```
t = "Breakfast at Tiffany's is a novella by Truman Capote."
```

The tokens data structure containing the original text indices and labels:

```
[(['Breakfast', 0, 9], 'BOOK'),
 (['at', 10, 12], 'BOOK'),
 (['Tiffany', 13, 20], 'BOOK'),
 (["'", 20, 21], 'BOOK'),
 (['s', 21, 22], 'BOOK'),
 (['is', 23, 25], 'O'),
 (['a', 26, 27], 'O'),
 (['novella', 28, 35], 'O'),
 (['by', 36, 38], 'O'),
 (['Truman', 39, 45], 'PER'),
 (['Capote', 46, 52], 'PER'),
 (['.', 52, 53], 'O')]
```

This data structure was generated from `t` as follows

```
import re

tokens = [[m.group(0), m.start(), m.end()] for m in re.finditer(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", t, re.UNICODE)]
tags = ['BOOK', 'BOOK', 'BOOK', 'BOOK', 'BOOK', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'PER', 'PER', 'O']
token_tuples = list(zip(tokens, tags))
```

What I would like my script to do is to iterate through `token_tuples` and if it encounters a non-`O` token, it breaks off from the main iteration and reconstitutes the tagged multi-token span until it hits the nearest token with `O`.

This is the current script:

```
for i in range(len(token_tuples)):

    if token_tuples[i][1] != 'O':

        tag = token_tuples[i][1]
        start_ix = token_tuples[i][0][1]

        slider = i+1

        while slider < len(token_tuples):

            if tag != token_tuples[slider][1]:

                end_ix = token_tuples[slider][0][2]

                print((t[start_ix:end_ix], tag))
                break

            else:
                slider+=1
```

This prints:

```
("Breakfast at Tiffany's is", 'BOOK')
("at Tiffany's is", 'BOOK')
("Tiffany's is", 'BOOK')
("'s is", 'BOOK')
('s is', 'BOOK')
('Truman Capote.', 'PER')
('Capote.', 'PER')
```

What needs to be modified so that the output for this example is:

```
> ("Breakfast at Tiffany's", "BOOK")
> ("Truman Capote", "PER")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution. If you can come up with something less long-winded, I'd be happy to choose your answer instead!

```
def extract_entities(t, token_tuples):

    entities = []
    tag = ''

    for i in range(len(token_tuples)):

        if token_tuples[i][1] != 'O':

            if token_tuples[i][1] != tag:
                tag = token_tuples[i][1]
                start_ix = token_tuples[i][0][1]

            if i+1 < len(token_tuples):

                if tag != token_tuples[i+1][1]:
                    end_ix = token_tuples[i][0][2]
                    entities.append((t[start_ix:end_ix], tag))
                    tag = ''

    return(entities)
```